# Почему-то изменения вступают в силу, только после перезагрузки страницы и то не сразу бывает, а со второго раза

Tags: php

Вообщем проблема заключается в том, что когда я записываю файл, то у меня при перемещении данные не показывает сразу.
А допустим когда я обновлю страницу.
Никак не могу понять, связи с чем это происходит. до этого, такого не было.

То есть вот этот банальный код:

```
public final function genFile($path, $content = '', $flag = 0, $context = null) {
    return false !== file_put_contents($path, $content, $flag, $context);
}
public final function redirect($url) {
    header('Location: ' . $url);
    exit;
}
```

То есть когда я делаю так:

```
if($this->genFile('fileName.txt','Text, text, text')) {
    $this->redirect('/url');
}
```

Все работает, файл записывает, без ошибок и т.д.
Перемещение происходит.
Но проблема, не показывает сразу после перемещения содержимое файла.
Показывает когда я обновлю страницу пару раз.

Кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой и почему так происходит?
Ранее такого не было, а вот сейчас стало вот так, работать.

На локалке стоит `WAMP` и сборка `php-7.3.1`.
Но опять - же, ранее такого не было, что могло произойти?

Comment: `opcache` включен?

Comment: @teran, да был включен, отключил. все заработало. Во дела то. Но дело в том, что я то не трогал настройки, я просто поменял версию, а там видимо по умолчанию все стояло и я даже не мог предположить, что такое может быть. Оформите пожалуйста ответ, чтобы я выбрал его в качестве решения, так как вы помогли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случаях, если работа кода не изменяется после обновления файлов скриптов, следует обратиться к механизмам кэширования. Кэшированием кода файлов занимается расширение OPCache (когда-то ранее было частью APC, потом появились OPCache (для кода) & APCu (для данных)).  Как и все другие модули, включается он в php.ini директивой `extension=opcache.dll` (в случае windows). В вашем случае расширение следует выключить.

Работать оно может в двух режимах. Либо с заданным интервалом проверять файлы на изменение и обновлять кэш, либо вообще не проверять его никогда.

На локальных рабочих станциях разработчиков, наверное, особого смысла включать это расширение нет.
На локальном сервере разработки, куда вы публикуете тестовые версии проекта, пожалуй есть смысл включить расширение, но настроить, таким образом, чтобы даты изменения файлов проверялись автоматически, либо весь кэш обовлялся автоматически .
На продакшен серверах чаще проверки изменений откдлючают, а кэш сбрасывают вручную после обновления кода проекта.

Различные массовые хостинги чаще выбирают стратегию номер 2, т.к. сложно будет объяснять клиентам, что им после правок надо еще и кэш сбрасывать вручную.