# как отключить кеш yii2

Tags: yii2

Прошу не тыкать носом в документацию, перешерстил всё абсолютно и перепробовал всё.
Сейчас так:

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params-local.php'
);

$config = [
    'id' => 'app-backend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'bootstrap' => ['debug'],
//    'bootstrap' => ['gii'],
    'modules' => [
        'debug' => [
            'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
            'allowedIPs' => ['**.**.**.**']
        ],
        'gii' => [
            'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
            'allowedIPs' => ['**.**.**.**']
        ],
    ],
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
//            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
            'class' => 'yii\caching\DummyCache',
        ],
        'db' => [
            'enableSchemaCache' => true,
        ],
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-backend',
            'cookieValidationKey' => $params['cookieValidationKey'],
            'baseUrl' => '',
        ],
        'assetManager' => [
            'baseUrl' => '/assets' //изменяется для подключения админки на локали
//            'baseUrl' => '@web/backend/web/assets' //изменяется для подключения админки на хостинге
        ],
//        'mailer' => [
//            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
//            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
//            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
//            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
//            // for the mailer to send real emails.
//    //            'useFileTransport' => true,
//            'transport' => [
//                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
//                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
//                'username' => 'admin@esot.net.ua',
//                'password' => 'X4C4>8jy',
//                'port' => '587',
//                'encryption' => 'tls',
//            ],
//        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-backend', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],
        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the backend
            'name' => 'advanced-backend',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],

        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'prices' => 'site/prices-category',
                'product' => 'site/prices-product',
                'logout' => 'site/logout',
                'login' => 'site/login',
                'test' => 'site/test',
                'gsc' => 'site/get-sub-categories',
                'auc' => 'site/add-user-categories',
                'test-response' => 'liqpay-response/index'
            ],
        ],

    ],
    'params' => $params,
];



unset($config['components']['cache']);


return $config;
```

в index.php вот так

```
<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/bootstrap.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php';

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../config/main.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php'
);

//echo '<pre>';print_r($config);


(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

но кеш по-прежнему включён. Это, наверное, ад кодера - дебажить с кешем:) Прошу помощи, как его отключить?

Comment: чего у вас кэшируется-то хоть скажите

Comment: кешируются вьюхи. А также если работаешь в контроллере и принтуешь код без вьюхи, то он тоже кешируется

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1099462/223826 проверьте, что у вас не аналогичная ситуация

Comment: "ад кодера - дебажить с кешем" - наличие или отсутствие кеша на ход отладки вообще никак не должно влиять, вы явно что-то не то делаете.

Comment: @user7860670 вы уверены, что вы и автор об одном и том же кэше говорите?

Comment: @teran вполне, я же говорю сразу о всех видах кеша, в которых могут оседать результаты работы приложения

Comment: @user7860670 а я про opcache. а автор вообще не определился еще.

Comment: @teran opcache тоже на ход отладки вообще никак не должен влиять

Comment: @user7860670 и действительно, в файле один код, в опкэше другой, но на отладку это никак вообще не влияет.

Comment: @teran Вот если в "файле один код, в опкэше другой" - то это явный признак того, что человек что-то делает не так...

Comment: @user7860670 в этом вся суть опкэша. Вопрос в том, что его не надо вообще включать на сервере разработок, или на локале.

Comment: не знаю, опкеш у меня или какой-то другой ибо не разбирался с этим. Видимо тот, который идёт по дефолту у yii2. Обратите пожалуйста, внимание на скриншот http://joxi.ru/LmG1ME6fJKQlGA тут видно, что при загрузке страницы используется ВЕРНЫЙ код, а ошибка отображается так, будто бы в коде реально есть ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Кеш у вас отсается по умолчанию(нужно дебажить какой) так как в конфигурации вы удаляете его следующей стокой

```
unset($config['components']['cache']);
```

#### В целом правильный подход такой

1) установить в конфигурации DummyCache

```
'components' => [
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\DummyCache',
    ],
],
```

2) после инициализации приложения проверьте, что вы действительно используете DummyCache в качестве компонента кеша

```
var_dump(\Yii::$app->cache)
```

Comment: у меня ж в конфигурации и так указан DummyCache. Строку, которую вы предлагаете удалить я нагуглил, решая этот вопрос. Но так как результата хоть с ней, хоть без неё нету, она и осталась. Закомментировал её. При вардампе yii\caching\DummyCache Object. Сейчас я в исходной позиции, с которой началось решение вопроса. И в этой позиции, как вы понимаете, кеш работает :)

Answer (score 1):

выражаю благодарность за ответ товарищу  **teran**. Да, действительно, дело было в опкеше, который я выключил в панели хостинга. Вот тут всё правильно написано ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1099462/223826
**teran** ответ дал в комментарии к вопросу, поэтому отблагодарил, как смог)

Comment: как правильно поступать, когда человек дал ответ в комментарии? Я на основании его ответа "ответил на собственный вопрос", но так ему не пошла репутация.

Comment: @Oughtem да всё нормально. Просто люди из очереди проверок иногда не понимают контекста ситуации)